# Can an Anti nuclear atom be synthesised so it can neutralise the effect of nuclear atom

Tags: nuclear-physics

as we have studied that if the number of electron becomes equal to number of proton then that particle becomes neutral. so what will the energy or procedure required to break the chain reaction  in that nuclear process so that it can never resume back.

Comment: Well i don't know that this method is already invented or not but if it can be made possible many people can be escaped from nuclear holocaust type situation.

Comment: Nope. If I may I would compare that to inventing water to combat fire. First you burn someone. After he is nice and crispy and quiet dead you douse him with water hoping that he comes back to life. Sadly that is not the way nature works.

Comment: At the moment the question here is very unclear. Both @Hennes and hdhondt have tried to understanding it, but the vastly different interpretation they have found suggest just how unclear. Could you re-phrase the question?

Comment: I hate to say this (I hate failing students), but you have some fundamental misunderstanding of physics possibly informed by a misreading of mysticism. There is no "nuclear" atom because nuclear is an adjective solely to describe technology. Rather, atoms have a "nucleus", a noun, as a necessary component. "The chain" cannot be neutralized because it is not a noun, but a verb to describe the actions of atoms and neutrons in a critical mass. At best it can be "stopped", by lowering control rods in a reactor, or if a bomb fizzles.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is some background.

Most atoms are neutral because they do have an equal number of protons and electrons. However, the electrons only control **chemical** reactions, not nuclear ones. Nuclear reactions happen in the nucleus, i.e. the neutrons and protons. In a nuclear fission bomb, the uranium and plutonium atoms are neutral - until the energy of the explosion strips the electrons of the atoms. In a fusion bomb, a fission reaction is used to first remove the electrons, so that the nuclei of the fissionable material (deuterium and tritium) can get into contact with each other and fuse.